# Android: translations in resources

Tags: java, android, xml

I have done translations for my app. Translations in folders "res/values-ru", "res/values", "res/values-rs"."res/values-sp", "res/values-cn" and so on.

But when I switch language on my phone, language in my app is English or Russian only.

What's wrong?

Comment: Please we need more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

correct suffixes for Chinese and Spanish are "-zh" and "-es"

ps. and German is "-de", just in case you might need it later.